# C Code, Help Needed with Randomized dice game not giving correct answer

Tags: c, random, dice

I am trying to make a game which randomizes 3 dice rolls, displays the first sum of the 3 dice and then asks the user if they think the sum of the next roll will be higher(h), lower(l) or the same(s). I feel I am close to having it working but when I run the game, I cant seem to get the user input to "line up" with what the answer should be (if that makes sense..).

Here is my code so far:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<ctype.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<math.h>
 #include<time.h>

 int main(){

   srand(time(NULL));
   char userInput;
   int diceOne=(rand()%6)+1;
   int diceTwo=(rand()%6)+1;
   int diceThree=(rand()%6)+1;
   int firstRoll = diceOne+diceTwo+diceThree;
   int prevSum,newSum;

   printf("***Welcome to the dice guessing game!***\n\n");
   printf("Rules:\n type 'quit' to exit game\n'h' for higher\n'l' for lower\n's' for same.\n\n"); 
   printf("dice one: %d\ndice two: %d\ndice three: %d\n",diceOne, diceTwo, diceThree);
   printf("The starting total is: %d\n",firstRoll);

   while(&userInput!="quit" ){

     void randDice (void){
       diceOne=(rand()%6)+1;
       diceTwo=(rand()%6)+1;
       diceThree=(rand()%6)+1;
     }

     printf("Guess:");
     scanf("%c\n\n",&userInput);

     prevSum = diceOne+diceTwo+diceThree;
     randDice();
     newSum = diceOne+diceTwo+diceThree;

     if((userInput=='h') && (prevSum > newSum)){
     printf("Correct!\n");
     printf("The sum of the three dice was: %d \n\n", prevSum);
   } else if((userInput=='l') && (prevSum < newSum)){
     printf("Correct!\n");
     printf("The sum of the three dice was: %d \n\n", prevSum);
   } else if((userInput=='s') && (prevSum == newSum)){
     printf("Correct!\n");
     printf("The sum of the three dice was: %d \n\n", prevSum);
   } else {
     printf("Incorrect\n");
     printf("The sum of the three dice was: %d \n\n", prevSum);
   }
 } 
 return 0;
```

}

The output from running this code is as follows:

```
***Welcome to the dice guessing game!***

Rules:
 type 'quit' to exit game
'h' for higher
'l' for lower
's' for same.

dice one: 3
dice two: 4
dice three: 1
The starting total is: 8
Guess:h
h
Incorrect
The sum of the three dice was: 8

Guess:h
Incorrect
The sum of the three dice was: 8

Guess:h
Correct!
The sum of the three dice was: 9

Guess:l
Incorrect
The sum of the three dice was: 4
```

As you can hopefully see, I have to enter two inputs the first time before the game will continue to run. In the example of the output I guessed h(higher) a few times and got it correct once when the sum of the dice changes form 8 to 9, but when I enter l(lower) and the dice change from 9 to 4, I get "incorrect".

Comment: What do you mean by "line up"? Can you please edit the question to include some example *actual* output, together with the *expected* output?

Comment: `scanf` doesn't recognize new lines, but input is processed only when a new line is entered. This makes input and output look out of sync. A better approach is to read whole lines first with `fgets` and thenscan the line with `strtok` or `sscanf`.

Comment: You are reading single characters, so your input can never be `"quit"`. Also, the address of `userinput` will not match the address of something else like a string literal. You need `strcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: Oh, and the expression `&userInput!="quit"` will *never* be true.

Comment: Most of logic is not correct, try to debug with gdb.

Comment: ahhh ok. I think I know what I need to do.
Thank you to everyone who commented

Comment: How does the code compile with the function being defined inside the loop? To compare strings you must use a function like strncmp

Answer (score 0):

```
  while(&userInput!="quit" ){
```

You are reading single chars in your function, which means this will never equal true.

```
  scanf("%c\n\n",&userInput);
```

Use `fgets` instead and then read that into a char with `sscanf`